# ActiveRecord object equality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, rspec-rails

According to docs of [ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-3D-3D):

> ==(comparison_object) Returns true if comparison_object is the same exact
>   object, or comparison_object is of the
>   same type and self has an ID and it is
>   equal to comparison_object.id.
>
> Note that new records are different
>   from any other record by definition,
>   unless the other record is the
>   receiver itself. Besides, if you fetch
>   existing records with select and leave
>   the ID out, you’re on your own, this
>   predicate will return false.
>
> Note also that destroying a record
>   preserves its ID in the model
>   instance, so deleted models are still
>   comparable.

But my observations show that it only compares instaces, not ids so that following are true:

```
a = Factory.create(:user)
b = User.find_by_email(a.email) # b is logically same as a

a.id.should == b.id # All good
a.should == b # FAILS: Contradicts the docs
a.should_not == b # Contradicts the docs
a.should_not eql b # Contradicts the docs
```

The question is 2 AR instances are considered to be different while the docs explicitly say that those should be equal?

**UPDATE:** The equality **DOES work as expected**. **Code sample above is irrelevant**. See my answer below.

Comment: Note: Current version of doc link above is at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-3D-3D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question (which is irrelevant).

All the equality checks DO work as expected (and described in the docs).
I assume the reason it did not work for me is that I run `autotest` and something could be cached or some other mythical reason that I can't explain right now.

To summarise, all the following assertions are indeed passing:

```
a = Factory.create(:user)
b = User.find_by_email(a.email) # b is logically same as a

a.id.should == b.id
a.should == b
a.should eql b
User.find_by_email(a.email).should == User.find_by_email(a.email)
a.should == User.find_by_email(a.email)
b.should == User.find_by_email(a.email)
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning autotest and caching, which explained issue I had as weel with watchr. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

Look closer at the definition: **Note that new records are different from any other record by definition**.

In this case, since AR normally just does equality checks to the identity column, you can compare the two objects by comparing the result of what #attributes return for each.

Comment: 2 records are different. But 2 objects with the same ID are logically equal (according to `ID .. is equal to comparison_object.id`). If that is true, I don't understand why `a == b` is `false` because it should be the same as `a.id == b.id` (which is `true`). Or I am missing something?

Comment: You are correct, but this is a special case because variable a contains a new record, and by definition a will not be equal to any other record. If you did User.find(:email..)==User.find(:email..) .. It will return true because not only are they the same record but neither of them are new.

Comment: No. Both `a` and `b` are NOT new records. `a.new_record?` and `b.new_records?` are `false`. They are just 2 different objects. Nothing to do with `User.find(..) == User.find(..)`. Additionally, right now my specs actually *work as the docs say* and I can use `a == b`. I guess there was a problem somewhere else. This means the my question is obsolete now and (as i expected) `a == b` are always true as long as they have same ID.